# diferença entre o merge ao cherry pick?

Tags: git

Qual a diferença entre o git cherry-pick e o git merge

Segundo a definição no proprio git

- git-cherry-pick - Apply the changes introduced by some existing commits
- git-merge - Join two or more development histories together

Porém criando um branch e fazendo o merge ou git-cherry-pick de um commit não consegui entender a diferença. Obrigada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `cherry-pick` recebe como argumentos uma lista de identificadores de commits.

Isto é, ele é usado da seguinte forma:

```
git cherry-pick commit1 commit2 ...
```

Com isso, ele irá pegar a diferença que cada um destes commits introduziu (pode ser vista com `git show commitX`) e aplicar na posição (`HEAD`) em que você está.

Então, algumas conclusões importantes:

- Esse commando não cria nenhuma conexão com o branch original de onde você trouxe o commit. A única conexão que existe é na mensagem do commit, o que só tem significado para o usuário que for ler (o git não usa essa informação).
- O git não vai ser capaz de identificar que essas diferenças ja foram aplicadas em um momento futuro. Vou dar um exemplo mais abaixo.
- Se você roda `git cherry-pick branchB`, ele **apenas** irá trazer a última modificação do branch B. Afinal de contas, `Branch B` é um identificador para o commit mais recente nesta branch.

Agora, comparando com `git merge`... Vamos supor o seguinte histórico de commits:

```
         Branch A
         |
1--2--3--4
   |
   5--6--7
         |
         Branch B
```

Se você estiver no `branch A`, e rodar o comando `git merge B`, os seguintes passos irão ocorrer:

- O git irá encontrar o primeiro ancestral comum aos dois branches. Neste caso é o commit `2`.
- Ele irá verificar a diferença entre `2` e `4`, e comparar com a diferença entre `2` e `7`. Essa comparação vai ditar a aplicação do merge.
- Isto é, ao final do merge, no `branch A` estarão contidas todas as alterações feitas no `branch B` desde seu primeiro ancestral comum (Commits `5`, `6` e `7`).
- Essas informações do merge também ficam salvas. Ou seja, se você em um futuro tentar fazer o merge do `branch B` com o `branch A` pela segunda vez, ele não irá aplicar essas modificações de novo. Isso é bem importante quando se trata de um número maior de `branchs` ou um de um fluxo de trabalho mais complexo.
- Outro exemplo: Se no seu branch original não tiver tido nenhum commit desde a criação do branch que está trazendo o merge (ou seja, não houve bifurcação), o git vai ser esperto e simplesmente "apontar" o branch A para o final do branch B (`Fast-Forward`). O cherry-pick iria duplicar todos os commits de um branch para o outro sem necessidade.

Resumidamente vemos que as diferenças são:

- O `merge` leva em consideração (e armazena) mais informações ao fazer o merge do que um simples cherry-pick.
- O `merge` irá trazer todas as diferenças desde o primeiro ancestral comum, enquanto o `cherry-pick` irá trazer apenas as diferenças dos commits especificados.
- O `cherry-pick` é útil, por exemplo quando você tem um commit que está no meio de outro branch (por exemplo, no desenho acima o `commit 6`), e você quer trazer apenas ele, sem trazer o resto do branch ou se preocupar com os conflitos que isso pode gerar. Isso deve ser feito com cuidado, pois se no futuro você tentar fazer o merge do branch, o git não vai saber que um commit intermediário já foi levado em consideração.