# É possível escolher os commits que eu queira adicionar em outra branch?

Tags: git

Supomos que eu tenha a branch `main` e a branch `release`.

Na branch `main` foram publicadas várias features, estas em commits separados.

**Problema:** Não quero que algumas dessas features seja enviada para o ambiente de produção, pois ainda estão em fase de testes.

Quando eu for fazer o merge da branch `main` para a branch `release` gostaria de selecionar as features que devem ser publicadas em ambiente de produção. É possível realizar isso através da seleção dos commits?

Comment: acho que seria mais fácil criar uma branch só com os commits que deseja e fazer merge dela :)

Comment: @RicardoPontual o problema que todas as alterações já estão na branch main. acredito que não consigo fazer isso não :(

Comment: Se entendi direito, uma alternativa é `git cherry-pick commit1 commit2 etc...` (coloque somente a lista dos commits que vc quer), assim ele só aplica os commits que vc indicar. Se fizer merge, não tem jeito, vai tudo

Comment: @hkotsubo pode dar uma exemplo?

Comment: Ué, o comentário acima é o exemplo :-) Vc vê quais são os commits que tem as features que vc quer, e no branch release vc faz o cherry-pick, passando os hashes desses commits

Comment: @hkotsubo vou fazer um teste aqui.

Comment: era exatamente o que o @hkotsubo comentou :)

Comment: @hkotsubo posta uma resposta ai. vou marcá-la como correta.

Comment: Uma boa ideia é repensar esse fluxo considerando esse tipo de situação. Pra este momento eu iria de cherry-pick mesmo.

Comment: @JéfBueno o problema que algumas features passaram do tempo previsto e o pessoal do negócio quer a publicação das outras, primeira vez que acontece esse caso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como cada *feature* está em um *commit* separado e você quer selecionar apenas algumas delas, o problema se resume a aplicar determinados *commits* no branch `release`.

Ou seja, basta usar o [`git cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick), passando os *commits* que você quer aplicar:

```
git cherry-pick commit1 commit2 commit3 etc...
```

Sendo que `commit1`, `commit2`, etc, são os hashes dos commits em questão (que você pode ver quais são com `git log`, por exemplo).

Um *merge* não funcionaria porque nesse caso todos os *commits* seriam aplicados, conforme já explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/481286/112052).